# python: split() splits quoted values too

Tags: python

I have a address like

```
line = 12345 North Drive,,"Palm Retreat, CO",CO,92261
```

When I split I get

```
line.split(",") 
['12345 North Drive', '', '"Palm Retreat', ' CO"', 'CO', '92261']
```

All I want is

```
'12345 North Drive', '', '"Palm Retreat CO"', 'CO', '92261']
```

What is that I am missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split()` is working as intended; it does not care about quotes. You may want to take a look at the `csv` module in conjunction with `StringIO`: you put your string in a `StringIO` object (which makes it look like a file) and then pass it on to `csv.reader`. Something like this:

```
import csv
from cStringIO import StringIO

s = "12345 North Drive,,\"Palm Retreat, CO\",CO,92261"
s = StringIO(s)
reader = csv.reader(s, delimiter=",")
for row in reader:
    print row
```

**Update**: actually, since `csv.reader` works with any iterable that yields lines (not just files), you can simply pass a list of lines to `csv.reader` without going through the `StringIO` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `csv` module to handle CSV data.